# Spring pagination does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestResource {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Integer>> test(Pageable pageable) {
        List<Integer> init = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new PageImpl<>(init, pageable, init.size()).getContent());
    }
}
```

Request */api/test?page=1&size=2* returns entire init list (from 1 to 10).
From logs:

> Enter: com.test.rest.TestResource.test() with argument[s] = [Page request [number: 1, size 2, sort: null]]

How to make it work?

Comment: @downvoter, can you provide an explanation of your vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, Page works with repositories only, so I found a solution:

Use org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Integer>> getIntegers(Pageable pageable) {
    List<Integer> init = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}));
    PagedListHolder<Integer> holder = new PagedListHolder<>(init);
    holder.setPage(pageable.getPageNumber());
    holder.setPageSize(pageable.getPageSize());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(holder.getPageList());
}
```

Request */api/test?page=1&size=2* returns [3,4]

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your calls.

1. new PageImpl<>(init, pageable, init.size()

PageImpl's Constructor

```
public PageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {
    // PageImpl subclasses Chunk
    super(content, pageable);
    ...
}
```

Chunk's Constructor

```
public Chunk(List<T> content, Pageable pageable) {
    Assert.notNull(content, "Content must not be null!");

    this.content.addAll(content);
    this.pageable = pageable;
}
```

2. PageImpl::getContent()

PageImpl doesn't implement this method, but Chunk does.

```
public List<T> getContent() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(content);
}
```

In summary, you set the value of content when you passed in `init` as a parameter to the constructor. When you called `getContent()`, you get more-or-less exactly what you put in originally.

Comment: Is it a way to get content by params?

Comment: No. The Page object is effectively a container for both the contents of that page and the pagination information.

Let's say that our universal set of elements is { e1, e2, e3, e4, ..., e_n } with a page size of 2. 

An example page object, p1, would have contents = {e1, e2} and would have a pageable with additional information like page number = 1, total page number = n / 2, etc.