# Spring boot testing error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page must not be null

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the following controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("movies")
public class MovieController {

    private MovieService movieService;
    private PagedResourcesAssembler<Movie> pagedAssembler;
    private MovieResourceAssembler movieResourceAssembler;

    @Autowired
    public void setMovieService(MovieService movieService) {
        this.movieService = movieService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPagedAssembler(PagedResourcesAssembler<Movie> pagedAssembler) {
        this.pagedAssembler = pagedAssembler;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMovieResourceAssembler(MovieResourceAssembler movieResourceAssembler) {
        this.movieResourceAssembler = movieResourceAssembler;
    }

    // Return all movies with pagination
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllMovies(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Movie> moviePage = this.movieService.getAllMovies(pageable);
        // Remove some unnecessary fields
        //this.movieService.removeUndesirableFieldsFromListing(moviePage);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.pagedAssembler.toResource(moviePage, this.movieResourceAssembler));
    }
 }
```

and here's the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MovieControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Test
    public void getAllMovies_PageableGiven_ShouldReturnMoviesPage() throws Exception {
        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        movieList.add(new Movie());
        movieList.add(new Movie());
        Page<Movie> moviePage = new PageImpl<>(movieList);
        given(this.movieService.getAllMovies(PageRequest.of(0,2)))
                .willReturn(moviePage);
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:8080/api/movies?page=1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

i got the following error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page must not be null!

Comment: Could you post full stafktrace?

Comment: Can you provide all the Java classes n Pom file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  Spring's mockMvc object injecting it inside your test class:

```
 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

I have just created a test method using mockMvc.perform method sending a page request:

My controller code:

```
@GetMapping(produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public List<BaseResponse> listAllBase(
        @PageableDefault(size = 50, page = 2) Pageable pageable) {

    // logger.debug("paginación recibida :{}",pageable);
    List<BaseResponse> findAllBases = baseService.findAllBases();
    return findAllBases;

}
```

My test code:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/base/?size=2&page=0")).andExpect(status().isOk())
             .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))                        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
             .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))                       .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
             .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", equalToIgnoringCase("margarita")))
```

See full Class code in my GitHub repo:

Controller:

https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-boot-mvc-complete-example/blob/develop/spring-boot-mvc-rest/src/main/java/com/mylab/cromero/controller/HelloWorldController.java#L53

Test class method:

https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-boot-mvc-complete-example/blob/develop/spring-boot-mvc-rest/src/test/java/com/mylab/cromero/controller/RestTestIT.java#L66

Feel free to use it in your project :)

Answer (score 0):

By reading these two Stackoverflow threads ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720768/spring-data-pageimpl-not-returning-page-with-the-correct-size) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839023/spring-pagination-does-not-work)) and also [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), it seems that you should use Page with repositories. Example:

```
PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> repository = // … get access to a bean
Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20));
```

For your case, it's recommended to use `PagedListHolder`, instead. Example:

```
List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
movieList.add(new Movie());
movieList.add(new Movie());
PagedListHolder<Movie> holder = new PagedListHolder<>(movieList);
```